# cannot access user data from social-auth-app-django

Tags: django, oauth, django-templates, django-authentication

I am overwhelmed by the authentication of Django and trying to wrap my head around it for a while.
i have used social-auth-app-Django to use OAuth for authorization from GitHub and Facebook.
GitHub worked and Facebook didn't worked, after log-in using GitHub I checked the admin page,
[image]

in the user social auths part i wasn't able to access the provider name using the template syntax in the html Page didn't showed up!

can someone explain what really going on here, and what is associations and nonces too?

this is my html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Document</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 {%if user.is_authenticated%}
 <h1>{{user.provider}}</h1>
 <h1>{{user.username}}</h1>



{%else%}
<h1>you are not logged in</h1>
{%endif%}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post your code instead of a Screenshot of the code..

Answer (score 0):

You can access provider by doing this :
in views.py

```
def get_provider(request):
    user= request.user
    user.social_auth.get(provider='provider name')
    provs= ['github','twitter','facebook','google-oauth2'] # Any backend in the social auth back end 
    found=list()
    notfound=list()

    for prov in provs :
    try:
        user.social_auth.get(provider=prov)
        print("Found ",prov)
        found.append(prov)
    except:
        print(prov,"Not found ")
        notfound.append(prov)
    
    return render(request, 'registration/social_login.html', {
    'found':found,
    'not_found':notfound,
    })
```

Then in your template 
social_login.html

```
{% for element in found %}
<p>you are auth as {{element}}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% for el in not_found %}
<p>you are not auth in {{el}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

You can found more here https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/24/how-to-add-social-login-to-django.html